# Reset wifi settings without factory reset in Android TV?

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, android-tv

So I've got a situation where I want to clear all saved networks. How can I do it without a factory reset?

Or, perhaps, do it using the Wifi Manager API?

I am using android box for TV, which is running 6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your version of Android, in Android 4.4 (KitKat) or lower the only option is a factory reset.

With the introduction of Android 5.0, including Lollipop, Marshmallow, Nougat, and Oreo versions of Android, Google added an option that is usually located in Settings - Backup & Reset that is called Network Settings Reset, which will reset all network related settings including all WiFi, Bluetooth, and Cellular Data settings back to their original factory defaults.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is go on WiFi settings and then tap or hold the WiFi you want to clear the click on disconnect then forget and it will be cleared